# filter data which doesn't start with list of letters in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I my query dosn't pull any data for this query in Oracle SQL developer can someone help?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City NOT LIKE '[bsp]%';
```

Comment: Use [REGEXP_LIKE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) instead of `like`

Comment: Please pay attention to the tabs Stack Overflow adds to your posts. In this case I will edit to remove the `MySQL` tag which is clearly out of place.

Comment: @krokodilko - `like` is superior if performance is important, since it will allow the use of an index on `city`. See Gurwinder Singh's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use regular expression (advised to avoid for decent size of data as it tends to be considerably slower than the alternate solution using simple `like` which can even be [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) sometimes) or use multiple conditions.

Using multiple conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City NOT LIKE 'b%'
and city not like 's%'
and city not like 'p%';
```

or using `regexp_like`:

```
select *
from customers
where not regexp_like(city, '^[bsp]');
```

Comment: I think above should be [bsp] only instead of ^[bsp]

Comment: @deepakl - No. The city name starts with b, s or p ... not contain b, s or p. [**Demo of `'[bsp]'`**](http://rextester.com/ROWS42332).... [**Demo of `'^[bsp]'`**](http://rextester.com/YLL1830)